# Pandas: compare element with another dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to write a script that would clean an excel file. I have 2 file - csv and excel. CSV file has 4 columns - id, email, date and client name. Excel has over 60 columns.

It (script) needs to compare if any of emails in csv file exist in excel file and if they do it needs to delete the entire row in excel.

How can I compare each row in csv.email column with excel['Email'] column?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a nice little function in Pandas called 'isin', this will check if values in column A are in column B.

```
csv[csv['mail'].isin(excel['mail'])]
```

That code will give all the rows in the csv that the mail column matches the mail column of the excel file.

Also, if you want the inverse, the rows of the csv files whose mails are not in the excel files you can do the following:

```
csv[~csv['mail'].isin(excel['mail'])]
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. I have tried it earlier and it gave me an error. After your suggestion i looked closer and found a typo. Thank you one more time!